# Problems with my BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python, basehttpserver

#### I am trying to create my own functions in the subclass of BaseHTTPRequestHandler as such

> class Weblog(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

```
def do_HEAD(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    self.end_headers()
def do_GET(self):
    """Respond to a GET request."""
    if self.path == '/':
        do_index()
    elif self.path == '/timestamp':
        do_entry()
    elif self.path == '/post':
        do_post_form()

def do_index(self):
    '''If the PATH_INFO is '/' then the weblog index should be presented'''
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    self.end_headers()
    post = None
    content = {}
    line = '<tr id="%(timestamp)s"><td>%(date)s</td>'
    line += '<td><a href="%(timestamp)s">%(title)s</a></td></tr>'
    for timestamp in weblog.list_posts():
        post = storage.retrieve_post(timestamp)
        if content.has_key('lines') == false:
            content['lines'] = line %post
        else:
            content['lines'] += line %post
    self.wfile.write('<a href = "post">Add a post</a>')
    self.wfile.write('<table><tr><th>Date</th><th>Title</th></tr>%(lines)s</tables>' %content)
```

When I run it on the commnadline it gives me the following error:-

> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59808)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 281, in _handle_request_noblock
> self.process_request(request, client_address)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py",   line 307, in process_request
> self.finish_request(request, client_address)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py",   line 320, in finish_request
> self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py",   line 615, in `__init__`
> self.handle()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py",   line 329, in hand
> self.handle_one_request()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 323, in handle_one_request
> method()
> File "weblog.py", line 34, in do_GET
> do_index()
> NameError: global name 'do_index' is not defined

### Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's worth noting that subclassing BaseHTTPServer is __not__ a serious way to create a blogging application in python: use pylons/turbogears/django, etc. instead. These are designed to use a __real__ webserver that is safe to expose on the internet.

Comment: Ah yes, I realise that, but it is just an assignment I have to do as per specifications. But thank you for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call something in the current class, you should use self.method_name()

```
def do_GET(self):
    """Respond to a GET request."""
    if self.path == '/':
        self.do_index()
    elif self.path == '/timestamp':
        self.do_entry()
    elif self.path == '/post':
        self.do_post_form()
```